# Syntax highlighting for context sensitive keywords

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to create a syntax highlighter for vscode. I've been making progress. However, there is a sequence that I just can't seem to get working.

I'm trying to highlight some identifiers, only within a certain section of code. In the following example, it's the keywords *public*, *private*, and *abstract*. They should only be highlighted after following the introducer keywords 'fn' or 'class', and also being enclosed within brackets.

```
fn [public] MyFunction() {}

class [private, abstract] MyClass {}
```

I'm trying variations of the following:

```json
"decorations": {
    "name": "decorations.lang",
    "match": "(fn|class)\\s*\\[\\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_, ]+)\\s*\\]",
    "captures": {
        "2": {
            "name": "decorations.captures.lang",    
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "entity.name.function.decorator.lang",
                    "match": "\\b(public|private|abstract)\\b"
                }
            ]
        }
    }                   
}
```

I checked that the "match" regex would match the above code. I used the following site:
https://rubular.com

The idea is to first match the stuff within the brackets, after seen one of the introducer keywords, and then do a submatch for the specific context keywords. When I check the tokens created, by using the vscode command `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`, no match gets made for the stuff in brackets.

**What is the correct setup to match those context sensitive keywords?**

Answer (score 0):

I rubber ducked myself. Right after I posted the question, the answer occurred to me.

The issue is that the highlighter definition has 2 sections, the "patterns" and the "repository".

```
{
    "patterns": [...],
    "repository": {...}
}
```

The patterns section, being an array, matches the entries in order. If another entry matches first, then rest are not tried. In my case, there was an entry matching the 'fn' and 'class' as keywords. After I moved the ref `#decorations` higher , within the 'patterns' section, it solved the issue.

However, that then creates an issue that the keywords won't get highlighted, in that case, because the context sensitive keywords are matched first. But, that's another problem.

Comment: then assign the correct scope to capture group 1

Comment: @rioV8 Can you please expand on that. I just, recently, started creating the vscode syntax for first time, and don't yet know the concepts well. How is the scope assigned? Do you mean the match, the name, or something else?

Comment: just like you give capture group 2 a scope